# JCO_ERROR_COMMUNICATION: Initialization of repository destination failed

Tags: sapjco3, sap-cloud-foundry

I am getting below error while trying to use SAP JCo3 in my Springboot application to access a backend BAPI deployed in SAP CF.

> Caused by: com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException: (102) JCO_ERROR_COMMUNICATION: Initialization of repository destination "XXXXX" failed: Opening connection to backend failed: There is no SAP Cloud Connector (SCC) connected to your subaccount matching the requested tunnel for subaccount "xxx" and SCC location ID "XXX-XX-XXX". Check the configuration on SCC and cloud side.

I am trying to call a BAPI using SAP Cloud SDK as specified in the below documents.

https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/bapi-and-rfc/overview

https://help.sap.com/docs/connectivity/sap-btp-connectivity-cf/on-premise-develop-sample-web-application#loio7808d1d32c994a9e860ab342e2188763__Include

Comment: Have you _"checked the configuration on SCC and cloud side"_?